# Sqlite Trigger Number of Rows Affected

Tags: database, sqlite, triggers

Need to keep running count of Rows in very large database. Row Count is needed enough times in my program that running Count(*) is too slow, so I will just keep running count to get around this in SQLITE.

```
CREATE TRIGGER RowCountUpdate AFTER INSERT ON LastSample
        BEGIN
        UPDATE BufferControl SET NumberOfSamples = NumberOfSamples + 
        (SELECT Count(*) FROM Inserted);
        END;
```

So from here I want to take the current number of rows (NumberOfSamples) and increment it with how many rows were affected by the insert (do same with DELETE and decrementing). In the C API of Sqlite, this is done with Sqlite3_Changes(). However, I cannot use that function here in this script. I looked around and saw that some were using the SELECT Count(*) FROM Inserted, but I don't think Sqlite supports that.

Is there any statement that Sqlite recognizes that holds the amount of rows that were affected by the INSERT and DELETE queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has the [changes() SQL function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#changes), but like the `sqlite3_changes()` API function, it reports the number of rows of the last *completed* statement.
During trigger execution, the triggering statement is not yet completed.

Just use a [FOR EACH ROW](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) trigger, and add 1 for each row.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, read that page and somehow overlooked it the first time. Thanks